# Changing each character's ASCII value in struct data type

Tags: c++, struct, ascii

As you can see from title I want to change each character's ASCII value in struct data type.
For this example I chose name and I want to change lowercase characters to uppercase characters (a to A and so on). I am also reading data from .txt file.
The words I want to "change" are:

```
Kayak
Ahmed
Samed
```

Here is the code I got so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct letterStr
{
    string name;
    string object;
};
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    ifstream letter;
    letterStr things[200];
    letter.open("pismo.txt");
    ofstream novoPismo;
    int numberOfThings= 0;
    while(letter >> things[numberOfThings].name >> things[numberOfThings].object)
    {
        numberOfThings++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThings; i++)
    {
       vector <letterStr> vec = {letterStr{things[i].name}};
       for (auto obj : vec)
       {
       if (obj.name.at(i) > 'A' && obj.name.at(i) < 'Z');
       obj.name.at(i) += 32;
       cout << obj.name;
       i++;
       }

    }
}
```

And here is the cout in console:

```
kayakSaìed
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: As you can see from the title I want to change the ASCII value of charachters and I do not know how to do it :)

Comment: Your second loop is strange. Incrementing i in the for and in the loop body looks wrong. Using the index for counting things and using it as a position into a string is wrong. Also building a vector with only one element and then range based for looping over it is just obfuscating.

Comment: The `ì` character (in your output) is not an ASCII character.

Comment: I don't know if [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uvBQzN8944qYxU66) is the sort of code you want. :/

Answer (score 1):

Well I think this

```
if (obj.name.at(i) > 'A' && obj.name.at(i) < 'Z');
    obj.name.at(i) += 32;
```

Should have been written like this

```
if (obj.name.at(i) >= 'A' && obj.name.at(i) <= 'Z')
    obj.name.at(i) += 32;
```

So >= not > and <= not <, but most importantly of all **no semi-colon at the end of the if statement**.

But there is an easier way

```
#include <cctype>

obj.name.at(i) = tolower((unsigned char)obj.name.at(i));
```

The `tolower` function converts an upper case letter into a lower case letter, and it works even if your system isn't using ASCII.

Comment: probably he needs the `toupper` function not `tolower`

Comment: A better thing would be to use something like `std::transform(name.begin(), name.end(), name.begin(), ::toupper);` If he wants to change all the characters.

Comment: Works for most single-byte encodings.  Not so good for multibyte encodings, such as UTF-8 or Shift JIS.

Comment: Doesnt work for me. I tried tolower  and touuper still doesnt work

Comment: @SamedŠkulj Post your latest code, you will probably be doing something else wrong.